# in-place plugins with Grails 2.0.0

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-2.0

I'm trying to upgrade a 1.3.7 app to 2.0.0.RC1. The app has a number of in-place plugins configured in BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.plugin.location."iris-licensing-plugin" = "${basedir}/../plugins/iris-licensing-plugin"
grails.plugin.location."ivdash" = "${basedir}/../plugins/ivdash"
grails.plugin.location."ivsecurity" = "${basedir}/../plugins/ivsecurity"
grails.plugin.location."ivmodel" = "${basedir}/../plugins/ivmodel"
grails.plugin.location."ivquery" = "${basedir}/../plugins/ivquery"
```

I ran "grails upgrade" on all these plugins, then ran "grails run-app" on the main app and got the following error:

> Packaging Grails application
>
> Error Plugin [ivmodel] is aliased as
>   [grails.plugin.location.ivmodel] to the location
>   [C:\workspace\fuse-view\fuse-view-web/../plugins/ivmodel] in
>   grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.
>
> You cannot upgrade a plugin that
>   is configured via BuildConfig.groovy, remove the configuration to
>   continue.

Any idea what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1):

I think some dependencies are missed after grails 2.0 migration.
Check repository urls for dependencies. 
Do not forget about [grails recommendations](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.RC1/guide/single.html#dependencyRepositories)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are [experiencing this issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8120).  I'm sorry to say I don't know how you can resolve it, but perhaps a trivial rename of each inline plugin will cause them to be treated 'fresh' by the build system, and avoid the need to nuke and pave?

Also make sure your plugins are only defined in the grails.plugin.location lines. Double check application.properties and that they are not in BuildConfig.groovy plugins{} block either